# How to loop over an array of random names and only console log a name with a particular length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over an array of random names and only console.log names that are greater than 5 in length.

```
var randomNames = ['Summer', 'Christabelle', 'Sam', 'Daniel'];

for ( i = 0; i < randomNames.length; i++) {
  if ( i > 5)
    console.log(randomNames[i]);
}
```

I don't know how to approach this exercise. Please help!

Comment: Check element's length and consider using `forEach` array method instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: what is the random approach of the question? do you want a single random name, which has a certain length?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking if `i < 5` (counter value), check for `randomNames[i].length < 5`  (element value's `length`)

```
var randomNames = ['Summer', 'Christabelle','Sam', 'Daniel'];

for ( i = 0; i < randomNames.length; i++) 
{
  if ( randomNames[i].length > 5) //observe the change here
  { 
    console.log(randomNames[i]);
  }
}
```

Or simplify this with `filter`

```
console.log( randomNames.filter( s => s.length > 5 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is checking the value of iterator i.e. `i`, instead you have to check the length of string at current iteration i.e  'randomNames[i].length > 5'. in if condition.

Comment: Thank you for the helpl!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to select particular names and `.forEach()` to log values instead of regular `for` loop:

```js
let names = ['Summer', 'Christabelle', 'Sam', 'Daniel'];

names.filter(({length}) => length > 5).forEach(n => console.log(n));
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Using modern JS and looking forward, I'd say the for loop was in fact the best option now, especially if you later wanted to use `async / await` within the loop.

eg.

```js
const randomNames = ['Summer', 'Christabelle','Sam', 'Daniel'];

for (const name of randomNames)
  if (name.length > 5) console.log(name);
```